# how to run flutter web build locally

Tags: flutter, dart, build, flutter-web

after:

```
flutter build web
```

built is ready in  path: build/web

how can I run it locally? without using

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Comment: the most simple way, step 1: `cd build/web`, step 2: `python -m http.server`

Comment: or when you dont have `python3` installed try one of those: https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255

Comment: you need a local web server. IIS, apache, nodejs or phython as @pskink mentioned

Comment: If your app uses any networking calls or is integrated with any services that do (like firebase), the python server approach won't work due to cross-site policies blocking all actions in modern web browsers. Run a local apache server instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74484793/2057171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## On Mac

Run the following terminal command to start up an apache server:

$ `sudo apachectl start`

Then, move the contents of your build/web folder to `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`

*(Note: Index.html base href should be `"/"` if you had previously modified it)*

Now, navigate web browser to `localhost`

Once done, kill the apache server with the following command:

$ `sudo apachectl graceful-stop`

---

## On Windows

[Download XAMPP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp), install, allow it to run on local networks if prompted, then launch the XAMPP app (it will likely have launched on its own).

In the XAMPP app, find the row for "Apache" and click the "Start" button to start up the web server

Move the contents of your build/web folder to `C:/xampp/htdocs/`

*(Note: Index.html base href should be `"/"` if you had previously modified it)*

Now navigate web browser to `127.0.0.1/index.html`

Once done, open the XAMPP app and click "stop" on the Apache row.